# iOS App only partially receives push-notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, certificate

I am facing a curious issue with an iOS app, that I am testing right now.
I'll try to sketch the situation as clearly as possible:

I am working with an iOS app, which comes in two "versions", although the term version can lead to confusion, since the code is the same.
This app is available for two different groups of people:
Internal version: "**Int**" - for co-workers
Production version: "**Prod**" - available in the app-store

Those two versions are managed on two different accounts:

**internal version** -> enterprise account

**public account** -> app store version

**Both** of those 'versions' are

1. capable of receiving push notifications
2. running with a Production Certificate

*The problem is: the app-store version is receiving push notifications just fine, while the internal version doesn't.*

I would like to understand why this is the case, since the two versions are absolutely identical in regards to code, they just differ in the way they are distributed.

**Further Information:**
 I'm sending test-pushes with Azure and Postman, both yield the same results. 
I'm using one CSR/certificate

I have tried:

- checked if the DNS is correct, they are
- re-newing all of the certificates, both prod and dev
- they both have explicit app-IDs
- Azure does seem to have issues with Dev-certificates, which is not the case here, since the issue only happens with Prod-certificates

I expect to receive push notifications on both versions, but on the interal version, azure gives only the result:

```
<NotificationOutcome xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Success>0</Success>
    <Failure>0</Failure>
    <Results i:nil="true"/>
</NotificationOutcome>`
```

Comment: I presume that the certificate you are using is from your app store account - you will need to use a certificate from your enterprise program account to send pushes to that version.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that right away. 
So it is most likely to be an issue with the certificates - the corresponding accounts. secondary, maybe how the internal version is rolled out (it is distributed via a server, maybe the iphones there have different settings)

Comment: Unfortunately, that was not the root of this issue, since we are using the certificate from the enterprise program account